# Error shows : The hierarchy of the type MainActivity is inconsistent as well as android.support.v4.app.Watson

Tags: java, android

Error shows : The hierarchy of the type MainActivity is inconsistent as well as android.support.v4.app.Watson. when I use SherlockFragmentActivity. I have imported  ActionBarSherlock  to my project and I use android.Support.v4.jar file. So please anyone help me to fix this problem.
//MainActivity code is Below :

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

// I also import :

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
```